# Dash (-) in front of bash

Tags: macos, bash

If I examine my bash shell in an OS X (10.6.4) terminal, such as by typing `echo $0`, there is a dash in front of my shell, like this: `-bash`. What does this dash mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means that `bash` is invoked as a login shell.

---

`man bash` says:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`, or one started with the `--login` option.
>
> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading  that  file,  it  looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.

---

You'll find `login -pf` in your `ps` output, which starts a login shell by default.

Try running `login -pf` and `login -pfl` and see the difference. `man login` describes the difference:

> `-l` Tells the program executed by login that this is not a login session (by convention, a login session is signalled to the program with a hyphen as the first character of `argv[0]`; this option disables that), and prevents it from `chdir(2)`ing to the user's home directory.  The default is to add the hyphen (this is a login session).

Comment: I am using ubuntu, and I see different behaviors of `echo $0`: if I type `echo $0` in the terminal invoked by `ctrl + alt + f1`, the result is `-bash`; but if I type it in termianl invoked by `ctrl + alt + t`, result is `bash`(no leading dash). Could you explain why?

Comment: @frozen-flame One is a login shell, the other isn't. Note that OS X Terminal and Linux terminals have different behavior in that regard.

Comment: @DanielBeck that's not a proof that the other isn't a login shell. When bash is launched with `--login` argument, it doesn't change its `argv[0]`, but does act as a login shell.

Comment: @Ruslan Sure, in theory it could still be a login shell. But it's not. (At least I'd be extremely surprised if it was.)

Comment: *It means that bash is invoked as a login shell.* Is there a source for it? That's true but I don't have any source. `man bash` doesn't say like "If bash is invoked with '-' as its first argument, the value of $0 is set to '-bash'". Your excerpt can be the source if `$0 == "-"` but actually `$0 == "-bash"`. Why does the word "bash" is appended?

Comment: @ynn `man login` mentions "_The default is to add the hyphen (this is a login session)_", which implies it's in addition to the regular name.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you. You are right. But it seems the excerpt is not enough. We shall cite the part *by convention, a login session is signalled to the program with **a hyphen as the first character of** `argv[0]`*. (By the way, only the Apple version of [`man login`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-498.2/login.tproj/login.1.auto.html) has that explanation. But there is no problem since OP is tagged with `macos`.)

Comment: @ynn I misunderstood your question then. It seemed to be more about why it's `-bash` and not just `-`.