# How to run sudo with target user environment AND without password prompt

Tags: shell, sudo, ubuntu-20.04

```
root@Test:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
root@Test:~#
```

I'm user1 and need to run a script as user2 and there must NOT be any password prompt.
Added below line to sudoers (using visudo of course)

```
user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

and then I ran the below command as user1

```
sudo -u user2 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

it runs but a part of actual execution fails becoz of user2 's environment is NOT set.

Then I tried below -

```
sudo -i -u user2 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

But it asks for the password, if I type in the password then the script runs just fine. The problem is that it prompts for password which is a problem for automation. So my query is how could I run sudo -i without password prompt.

My setup:

```
root@Test:~# egrep "^[^#]|^#include" /etc/sudoers
Defaults env_reset
Defaults mail_badpass
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/script.sh
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
root@Test:~#
root@Test:~# ls /etc/sudoers.d
README
root@Test:~#
```

Looks like setting the target user's ENV variables in the script itself is the only option but updating script is my last option, hence looking for a better/alt solution.

Appreciate any help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what `-i` does [emphasis mine]:

> `-i`, `--login`
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.login will` be read by the shell. **If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell as a simple command using the `-c` option.** The command and any arguments are concatenated, separated by spaces, after escaping each character (including white space) with a backslash (`\`) except for alphanumerics, underscores, hyphens, and dollar signs. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed. […]

<sup>([source](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudo.man/#i))</sup>

You tried to do:

> ```
> sudo -i -u user2 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
> ```

Assuming the target user's shell is `bash`, the command that your `sudo` run was like:

```
/bin/bash -c /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

This is the command you want to allow with `NOPASSWD` in `sudoers` file. Note there is no `-l` that would force a login shell. `sudo` sets `$0` to `-bash` and [the leading dash is what makes this `bash` a login shell](https://superuser.com/a/278865/432690). Therefore you must not include `-l` in `sudoers`.

```
user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

If the target user's login shell is not `/bin/bash` then adjust the above line accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, worked great :) Can't upvote as I need 15 rep sorry but marked it as Solution.